# PowerShell Event Log: remove header row from display (format-table)

Tags: powershell

I would like the entries in the red square removed (see screenshot).
I want the values with no header.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/data/errors unless there is no other reasonable way to show the needed info. why force those who want to help to squint to read your text? why force those who want to help to type in your text for testing _when you already have it as text_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
Get-EventLog security | select EventID, EntryType, Message | select -fist 10 | ft -Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

***Please have in mind the first comment you got on your question.***

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-EventLog security | select EventID, EntryType, Message | select -first 10| ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim()
```

- `ft -HideTableHeaders` taking advantage of the hideTableHeaders switch in the `format-table` cmdlet to remove the headers
- `Out-String` to ensure the output is in string format
- `Trim()`to remove any line-breaks

Answer (score 0):

Why would you be formatting this to a table? As stated before, this is almost always a wrong choice. 
Certainly when you want to alter/use it afterwards. (Which the user is supposedly going to do.)

```
(Get-EventLog security | select EventID, EntryType, Message | select -first 10).EventID
(Get-EventLog security | select EventID, EntryType, Message | select -first 10).EntryType
(Get-EventLog security | select EventID, EntryType, Message | select -first 10).Message
```

Or better: save it as a variable and loop through all the logs one-by-one:

```
$logs = (Get-EventLog security | select EventID, EntryType, Message | select -first 10)
foreach ($log in $logs) {$log.eventid;$log.entrytype;$log.message}
```